# What is the weakness of WiFi attacks?

Tags: wifi, password-cracking

I did not come to anything after searching Google for some time.

What's preventing someone from just doing an WiFi attack using AirCrack and do any kind of attack once logged on the victims network?

Comment: The law? The fact that "only plain brute force techniques can be used against WPA/WPA2" (aircrack docs)? "For a good, long password, it could take years, possibly even hundreds of years or longer."

Answer (score 2):

From a technical standpoint, there's no "just" to "just doing an aircrack wifi attack".

Almost all wifi networks these days use WPA or WPA2 security.  Logging into the network without authorization requires capturing a four-way handshake (easy), and then brute-forcing the password (very, very hard).  Unless the network administrator has selected an easy-to-guess password, this brute-force attack will take years.

WEP has algorithmic weaknesses that let it be cracked in a matter of minutes, but almost nobody uses WEP anymore.

Comment: http://www.hotforsecurity.com/blog/25-percent-of-wireless-networks-are-highly-vulnerable-to-hacking-attacks-wi-fi-security-survey-reveals-1174.html

Comment: That blog post dates from 2011.  These days, "default credentials" are usually randomized at the factory, and WEP has continued to decline in use.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the limiting factor is most definitely time.
Most people will use the password on the router that their ISP gave them and that ought to be a strong enough password by itself. If they do change it, then as long as it's not a single dictionary word then it should also be fine.

As an example from a website I found:

Brute Force Calculator
Password Length 10
Keys per second ~8mil
Charset [len:77] Alpha-numeric-symbols
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_+=

To brute force the entire keyspace it will take about
29 thousand years

More specifically
28805 years 301 days 7 hours 35 minutes and 38 seconds
(7423084163014967000 password combinations)

http://calc.opensecurityresearch.com/

Dictionary attacks are a whole different deal, but that requires more effort before hand. 
Here is a website that takes dictionary attacks into account:
https://passfault.appspot.com/password_strength.html#menu